# Loss tensor being pruned out of graph in PopART

Tags: ipu, popart

I’ve written a very simple PopART program using the C++ interface, but every time I try to compile it to run on an IPU device I get the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of ‘popart::error’ 
  what(): Could not find loss tensor ‘L1:0’ in main graph tensors
```

I’m defining the loss in my program like so:

```
auto loss = builder->aiGraphcoreOpset1().l1loss({outputs[0]}, 0.1f, popart::ReductionType::Sum, “l1LossVal”);
```

Is there something wrong with my loss definition that’s resulting in it being pruned out of the graph? I’ve followed the same structure as one of the Graphcore examples [here](https://github.com/graphcore/examples/blob/master/code_examples/popart/custom_operators/cube_op_example/cube_fn_custom_op.cpp).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error usually happens when the model protobuf you pass to the `TrainingSession` or `InferenceSession` objects doesn’t contain the loss tensor. A common reason for this is when you call `builder->getModelProto()` before you add the loss tensor to the graph. To ensure your loss tensor is part of the protobuf your calls should be in the following order:

```
... 
auto loss = builder->aiGraphcoreOpset1().l1loss(...); 
auto proto = builder->getModelProto(); 
auto session = popart::TrainingSession::createFromOnnxModel(...); 
...
```

The key point is that the `getModelProto()` call should be the last call from the `builder` interface before setting up the PopART session.